# Need help extracting numbers from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, svg, raphael, snap.svg

I need a rock solid RegExp to try and solve some issue with Raphael.js `parseStringPath` processing regarding Arc path commands and possible others (SnapSVG also inherits the problem). You see, `arcTo` path command accepts 7 coordinates and settings, but some strings might be malformed due to extreme optimization and the browser doesn't flag them, rather renders them properly. Check [Raphael.js demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/yq42njsr/).

Have a look at this example, I'm using the RegExp from Raphael.js and a very simplistic example with my own RegExp called `incorrectReg`, trying to break strings like `000` into [`0`,`0`,`0`] or `011` into [`0`,`1`,`1`].

```js
let spaces = "\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x20\xa0\u1680\u180e\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000\u2028\u2029",
    pathValues = new RegExp(`(-?\\d*\\.?\\d*(?:e[\\-+]?\\d+)?)[${spaces}]*,?[${spaces}]*`, `ig`),
    incorectReg = new RegExp(`([${spaces}]*0(?=[a-z0-9])|([${spaces}]\\0)*0(?=[a-z0-9]*))`, `ig`); // THIS ONE

function action(){
  let input = document.getElementById('input'),
      output = document.getElementById('output'),
      pathValue = input.getAttribute('d'),
      segments = pathValue.replace(/([a-z])/gi,'|$1').split('|').filter(x=>x.trim()),
      pathArray = []
      
  segments.map(x=>{
    let pathCommand = x[0],
        pathParams = x.replace(pathCommand,'').trim()
        
    pathArray.push( [pathCommand].concat(
      pathParams.replace(',',' ')
                .replace(pathValues,' $1 ')
                .replace(incorectReg,'$1 ')
                .split(' '))
                .filter(x=>x)
    );
  })
  output.setAttribute('d',pathArray.map(x=>x.join(' ')).join(''))

  console.table(pathArray)
}
```

```css
svg {max-width:49%}
```

```html
<button onclick="action()">Extract</button>
<hr>
<svg viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path id="input" d="M2,0a2 2 0 00,-2 2a2 2 0 002 2a.5.5 0 011 0z" stroke="red" stroke-width="1px" fill="none"></path>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path id="output" d="M0 0" stroke="green" stroke-width="1" fill="none"></path>
</svg>
```

As you can see in your browser console, we already solve the `000` group (which is obviously not a valid number, boolean, or anything specific), we just have to solve `011` and `11`, where all these groups are in fact a string of booleans.

So again, the `arcTo` path command works with

```js
arcTo -> ['A', rx,    ry,    xAxisRotation, largeArcFlag,  sweepFlag,     x,     y]
       // str, float, float, float,         boolean (0|1), boolean (0|1), float, float
```

I need a better `incorrectReg` RegExp and a combination of solutions to properly handle mainly `arcTo`, and other similar cases. Open to any suggestion.

Thank you

Comment: Do you strictly need regexp, or you just want the `d` attribute to be split into components? Writing a simple parser is IMO not difficult task and you can adjust it to all these "overoptimizations" (omitting spaces before decimal separator and minus, omitting lineTo commands...)

Comment: I need a combination of any RegExp + other solution, I know about fontello/svgpath.js but that guy is parsing the string character by character, it doesn't fail, but my code is totally backed by Raphael, so I need a combined solution.

Comment: What is wrong with "parsing the string character by character"?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not really catch where the problem is :-D that Raphael does not parse correctly some path strings?

Comment: Correct. If you check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yq42njsr/) Raphael.js fails to compute a similar situation of over-optimization.

Comment: Ok, so what is the problem with "3rd party" solution and pre-parsed path array?

Comment: Most 3rd party script fail to compute overoptimized path strings. I won't include stuff like D3.js or Paper.js, I'm happy with `pathToAbsolute` and `pathToCurve` from Raphael.js, trying to fix them.

Comment: I think there must be some lightweight libraries for that.. If not, you can create your own and publish it ;-)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I'm stuck with RegExp issues I was expecting to never fail and cannot easily solve.

Comment: it was my point, sorry for not being clear enough - use / write a parser not based on regexp, but rather on "character-by-character" parsing

Comment: Your `incorectReg` will never match, since you omitted `[]` around all the space characters - now all of them must appear **and** also in that order. Are you sure you even know what a regex is?

Comment: @AmigoJack I've updated the RegExp, but both versions produce the same effect (among others), since I can't seem to be able to target the `11` string, I already followed the above suggestion and I eliminated the issue, will probably submit a PR at Raphael as soon as it's triple checked.

Comment: Perhaps ``incorectReg = new RegExp(`(?<=[01${spaces}]+)([01])[${spaces}]*`, `g`);`` See https://regex101.com/r/GVOHEy/1 and replace with the full match `.replace(incorectReg,'$& ')`

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you, this RegExp is good, however that's not enough for instance `1.874` is a Boolean (4th param) and a Float (5th param), I will probably post a PR for Raphael directly with our finding. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the discussion below OP, I propose not to use regexp, but rather a proper parser (or lexer or tokenizer or how to correctly call it).

You can

- write your own parser (nice excercise)
- use something existing, e.g. I have successfully tried
  [svg-path-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-path-parser).

I am not even sure if such "super"regexp is possible to create.. Anyway you can use "sub"regexp in the parsing process :-)

Comment: Thanks man, already done. I cannot use that parser as it doesn't seem to be ES6/ES7 and its last update is 3 years "old". I'm preparing a PR to Raphael as soon as I finished all testing. Thank you and have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity and serving the community, I will post a working solution, it might help somebody in the future.

Unfortunately the `incorrectReg` RegExp, good or bad cannot work because it can also change other values as well (EG: `M0,11` returns `["M",0,1,1]` with the RegExp provided by [TheFourthBird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird)), so yea [Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2700104/jan-str%c3%a1nsk%c3%bd), you were right!

Here's a working solution, please feel free to edit or add more clarity if you like. Once we all agree on a rock solid solution, I will submit a PR to Raphael right after.

```js
let spaces = "\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x20\xa0\u1680\u180e\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000\u2028\u2029",
    pathValues = new RegExp(`(-?\\d*\\.?\\d*(?:e[\\-+]?\\d+)?)[${spaces}]*,?[${spaces}]*`, `ig`),
    incorrectReg = new RegExp(`(?<=[01${spaces}]+)([01])[${spaces}]*`, `g`); // FIXED ONE

function action(){
  let input = document.getElementById('input'),
      output = document.getElementById('output'),
      pathValue = input.getAttribute('d'),
      segments = pathValue.replace(/([a-z])/gi,'|$1').split('|').filter(x=>x.trim()),
      pathArray = []
      
  segments.map(x=>{
    let pathCommand = x[0],
        pathParams = x.replace(pathCommand,'').trim();

    pathParams = pathParams.replace(',',' ')
                .replace(pathValues,' $1 ')
                                /* .replace(incorrectReg,' $& ') */
                .split(' ').filter(x=>x);

    if ( pathCommand.toLowerCase() === 'a' && pathParams.length < 7){
      for (let i=0, ln = pathParams.length; i<ln; i++){
        if ( (i === 3 || i === 4) && pathParams[i].length > 1 ) {
          pathParams = pathParams.slice(0,i) // first part of array
                        .concat(pathParams[i][0]) // extract largeArcFlag OR sweepFlag
                        .concat(
                            pathParams[i].slice(1).replace(/(\-\d|\-\.\d|\.\d*(?=\.))/g,'|$1').split('|'), // get sweepFlag
                            pathParams.slice(i+1)) // continue after flags
                        .filter(x=>x) // remove added empty "space" items
          ln = pathParams.length // update length
        }
      }
      if (pathParams.length === 7) {
        pathArray.push([pathCommand].concat(pathParams.splice(0, 7)));
      } else {
        throw Error(`arcTo requires 7 coordinates, only ${pathParams.length + ' given: ['+pathParams.join(',')}]`)
      }
    } else {
      pathArray.push( [pathCommand].concat(pathParams) );
    }
  })
  output.setAttribute('d',pathArray.map(x=>x.join(' ')).join(''))

  // console.log(pathArray)
}
```

```css
svg {max-width:49%}
```

```html
<button onclick="action()">Extract</button>
<hr>
<svg viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path id="input" d="M2 0a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2h12a2 2 0 002-2V2a2 2 0 00-2-2H2zm7.5 11h-4a.5.5 0 01-.5-.5v-4a.5.5 0 011 0v2.793l4.146-4.147a.5.5 0 01.708.708L6.707 10H9.5a.5.5 0 010 1z" fill="red"></path>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path id="output" d="M0 0" fill="green"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Consider adding a lot of tests to be really "rock solid" and publishing it e.g. on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) as a (one of?) reference path string parsing library :-). Apart from svg-path-parser, I have tried several other packages, but all failed. Even such a "big" lib as [svg.js](https://svgjs.com) failed to parse the string correctly (I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/issues/1145))

Comment: No, this is anything but conforming and working. 1. It does not provide for the repetition of sequences without explicit use of command letters - an `A` could be followed by 7, 14, 21... numbers, representing 1, 2, 3 arc segments. 2. The `e` of an exponential will be misinterpreted as a path command. 3. Numbers can start with a `+` sign, not only a `-` or none. 4. A wide range of invalid sequences will not be caught. Please refer to the canonical [BNF](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataBNF) grammar.